# trying to toggle a container on one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I am trying to make a div container expand and contract every time an even handler is clicked.
However, every time I load the page, I have to click the even handler twice to expand it for the first time, after that it works with one click but I would like to only click it once to get it to expand upon page reload.

CSS:

```
#bodywrap1{
border-radius: 5px;
height: 00px ;
width: 80% ;
overflow: hidden;
border-top: solid 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
```

Javascript:

```
function expand(){
  $("#bodywrap1").toggle(function(){
  $("#bodywrap1").animate({height:600},200);
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<h2 onclick = "expand()" id = "expandv">Expand</h2>
```

Here is the site im working on, and the page specifically.
http://hourtimeagent.com/html/c++.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle works based on the display property, so set the `display: none` to the `bodywrap1`

When the first click happens, since the display is not set, instead of displaying the element `toggle()` hides it, to fix it set

```
#bodywrap1 {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 0;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: solid 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    /*new property*/
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, after reviewing all the answers I think yours is the best because of the simplicity and because I had to write only one more line of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's taking two clicks is because the .toggle hides the #bodywrap1, and then on second click it shows the #bodywrap1 and animates the height.

I fixed this by using .toggleClass instead and changed some things around with the css

http://jsfiddle.net/PUCLM/1/

HTML

```
<h2 id="expandv">Expand</h2>
<div id="bodywrap1">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#bodywrap1{
border-radius: 5px;
height: 0px;
width: 80%;
overflow: hidden;
border-top: solid 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
    background: blue;

}

#bodywrap1.theclass {
    height: 600px;
}
```

jQuery UI (you can only animate height with jQuery UI, not plain jQuery)

```
$('#expandv').click(function() {
  $("#bodywrap1").toggleClass('theclass', 500);
});
```

Comment: I applied yours and it works well except for the fact that it loses the animation. But thanks for specifiying what kind of Jquery is needed for that I didn't know.

Comment: Will have to come back after an errand and check up on the rest.

Comment: @BryanFajardo Well, let me know what animation your looking for. Because it does animate the height for me in the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Your html is not correctly written, remove from  <head> tags h1 and h2.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/c++.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<h1>C++</h1>
<h2 id = "expandv">Expand</h2>
<h1>Variables</h1>
<!-- ... -->
```

Change your javascript for the following:

```
$(function() {
    function expand() {
        $("#bodywrap1").toggle(function(){
           $("#bodywrap1").animate({height:600},200);
        });
    }

    // Click function for #expandv item
    $("#expandv").on("click", function() { expand(); });

    // Initialize a hidden wrap
    $("#bodywrap1").css("display", "none");
});
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TFZ4R/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the html errors and the code worked great its just a bit more complicated for me atm.